# Small Bayes Calculator to learn Javascript

Tags: javascript, css, sass

I am trying to learn UI design so I threw together a Bayes Calculator (i.e. calculate the posterior probability of being sick given a positive/negative test result using the specificity, sensitivity of the test and current incidence rate). Since I already wrote markdown for a static site generator (hugo) I similarly created a html content page which is wrapped by the [hugo theme fuji](https://github.com/dsrkafuu/hugo-theme-fuji/). This theme did not include styling for input elements (likely because it is intended for blogpost like markdown and not html). So I had to add some custom SCSS styling (but using existing color variables). In particular I added some logic to only activate form validation styling once an input element was modified once (add the class "wasModified").

The end result looks like this:

[image]

I am unsure how to align the input elements. A table would work, but then I lose the wrap around on mobile putting the labels above the input fields. Are there any best practices?

#### HTML

```html
<!--content/blog/tools/bayes-helper.html -->
---
title: Bayes Helper
date: "2022-01-22"
tags: [maths, tools, health]
draft: true
---
<form id="bayes-form">
    <label for="incidence">Incidence Rate</label>
    <input type="number", id="incidence", name="incidence", min="0", max="100000", step="1", placeholder="per 100 000", required> 
    <br>
    <label for="sensitivity">Sensitivity</label>
    <input type="number", id="sensitivity", name="sensitivity", min="0", max="100", step=".01", placeholder="in percent", required> 
    <br>
    <label for="specificity">Specificity</label>
    <input type="number", id="specificity", name="specificity", min="0", max="100", step=".01", placeholder="in percent", required> 
    <br>
    <label for="test_positive">Test positive?</label>
    <input type="checkbox", id="test_positive", name="test_positive"> 
    <br>
    <label for="posterior" >Likelihood to be infected:</label>
    <output id="posterior" name="posterior">Input not Valid</output>
</form>

<script>
    function _calculatePosterior(prior, sensitivity, specificity, test_positive) {
        const p_test_given_pos = test_positive ? sensitivity : 1-sensitivity
        if (prior==0 || p_test_given_pos == 0){
            return 0
        }
        const p_test_given_neg = test_positive ? 1-specificity : specificity
        return 1/(1+ p_test_given_neg*(1-prior)/(p_test_given_pos*prior))
    }

    function calculatePosterior() {
        this.posterior.value = _calculatePosterior(
            this.incidence.value/100000.0,
            this.sensitivity.value/100.0,
            this.specificity.value/100.0,
            this.test_positive.checked
        ) *100 + "%";
    }
    document.getElementById("bayes-form").oninput = calculatePosterior
    document.getElementById("bayes-form").onreset = calculatePosterior

    function add_wasModified() {
        this.classList.add("wasModified");
    }

    for (const input of document.getElementsByTagName("input")) {
        input.oninput = add_wasModified;
    }
</script>
```

#### SCSS

```
// assets/scss/_custom_rules.scss
// Override CSS rules with that file
input {
    color: var(--color-font);
    background-color: var(--color-bg);
    border: 2px solid var(--color-divider);
    border-radius: 2px;
    padding: 5px;
    margin: 10px;

    &:hover {
        border: 2px solid var(--color-primary);
    };

    accent-color: var(--color-primary);
}
input.wasModified:invalid {
    border: 2px solid $border-red-light;
}
button {
    color: var(--color-font);
    background-color: var(--color-codebg);
    border-color: var(--color-primary);
    border-radius: 2px;
}
```

#### Appendix: Math

For those interested (on request). So "sensitivity" is the likelihood of a test being positive conditional on truly having the condition, let us denote this by
$$P(\text{test_p}|\text{pos})$$
"Specificity" is the likelihood of a test being negative conditional on not having the condition (being negative), denoted by
$$P(\text{test_n} | \text{neg})$$

Now we want to know the probability of having the condition conditional on the test result, i.e.

$$\begin{align}
P(\text{pos}|\text{test})
&= \frac{P(\text{pos}, \text{test})}{P(\text{test})} 
= \frac{P(\text{test}| \text{pos})
P(\text{pos})}{P(\text{test}, \text{pos})
+P(\text{test},\text{neg})}\\
&=\frac{
    P(\text{test}| \text{pos})P(\text{pos})
}{
    P(\text{test}| \text{pos})P(\text{pos})
   +P(\text{test}|\text{neg})(1-P(\text{pos}))
}\\
&=\frac{1}{1+\frac{
P(\text{test}|\text{neg})(1-P(\text{pos}))
}{
    P(\text{test}| \text{pos})P(\text{pos})}
}
\end{align}$$

Okay so what do we need to calculate this. First of all we need the prior probability to have the condition (before doing the test), P(pos), this is the incidence rate. For the two conditional probabilities we need we just need to look at specificity and sensitivity. For a positive test result we have

$$\begin{align}
P(\text{test} | \text{pos}) 
&= P(\text{test_p} | \text{pos}) =\text{specificity}\\
P(\text{test} | \text{neg}) 
&= P(\text{test_p} | \text{neg}) = P(\text{test_n} | \text{neg}) = 1-\text{sensitivity}
\end{align}$$
for a negative test result we have
$$\begin{align}
P(\text{test} | \text{pos}) 
&= P(\text{test_n} | \text{pos}) = 1- \text{specificity}\\
P(\text{test} | \text{neg}) 
&= P(\text{test_n} | \text{neg}) = \text{sensitivity}
\end{align}$$

This explains the ternary operator. Then you just need to do some considerations for the probability zero cases and you just need to type up the algorithm.

Comment: Could you consider posting the actual math? I believe many users might be interested in it.

Comment: @coderodde I added an appendix (as a picture because stackexchange detects latex as code and complains that I do not use code fences)

Comment: wrt to LaTeX see: https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10757/make-the-codeblock-detection-less-aggressive

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### UX

Overall, fine. Good use of labels.

Getting an invalid input error off the bat is a bit jarring.

Consider formatting the result to a readable number of decimal places (say, 2) unless you have good reason to be more precise.

#### Code style

In general, try to stick to conventions and be consistent.

##### JS

- JS uses camelCase rather than snake_case (`p_test_given_pos`). `add_wasModified` uses a mix and isn't a style I see much of in JS.
- Add space between operators: `if (prior==0 || p_test_given_pos == 0){` should have `prior == 0`. `return 1/(1+ p_test_given_neg*(1-prior)/(p_test_given_pos*prior))` is clearer with intermediate variables and spaces around operators. These are good variable names, though.
- [Use `===` always](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/359494/which-equals-operator-vs-should-be-used-in-javascript-comparisons). `==` does confusing type coercions so it can easily lead to bugs. Always using `===` eliminates all of these bugs and improves readability by making intent explicit (explicitly coerce when necessary).
- Stick to using semicolons after every statement or skip them entirely except when necessary. It's more common to use them. Once again, it eliminates a whole class of bugs, quickly becomes second nature, and isn't really less "clean" looking in my opinion. I doubt it impacts development speed meaningfully. See [Do you recommend using semicolons after every statement in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/444080/do-you-recommend-using-semicolons-after-every-statement-in-javascript)
- I'm not sure why `_calculatePosterior` has a leading underscore. I guess because it's a "private" helper function for `calculatePosterior`, which does DOM interaction and formatting. It's good to separate the two, but maybe choose clearer variable names. For the handler, you can use `handlePosteriorRecalculation` (since it's an event handler) and `calculatePosterior` for the non-I/O math. I typically see leading underscores for private class methods and variables, neither of which applies here.
- JS usually uses 2-space indentation. I see 4 from time to time, so it's a minor point.

##### CSS

- CSS names usually use kebab-case, so `wasModified` would be `was-modified` (I'd just call it `modified` though). But you got it right with `bayes-form` (although "form" might be redundant -- maybe `form.bayes-calculator` is clearer? I don't know the best practice here).
- Your SCSS structure looks fine but perhaps move `accent-color: var(--color-primary);` up above the `&hover` block.
- In a larger app, scope your CSS selectors specifically: `.bayes-calculator input` instead of `input`.

##### HTML

- In the HTML, `type="number", id="incidence", ...` shouldn't have commas.
- I don't like long HTML lines for the same reason as long code lines. I suggest:

  ```html
  <input
    type="number"
    id="incidence"
    name="incidence"
    min="0"
    max="100000"
    step="1"
    placeholder="per 100 000"
    required
  >
  ```
- Don't use `<br>` for styling; it's inflexible and semantically conflates structure (HTML) with style (CSS). Prefer CSS's `margin-bottom` and `display: block` or similar. If these are block lines, wrap them in `<div>`s or wrap the `<label>` around the `<input>` instead of using `for=`. `<br>` is only for breaks in `<p>` elements, as in an address. See [When to use <p> vs. <br>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13688158/when-to-use-p-vs-br).

#### Code design

There's not much of an app to speak of design, so this is premature, but...

Usually, functions with a flag that switches between multiple behaviors is poor design. This has been given comprehensive treatment elsewhere, so I'll just point the way: [Is it wrong to use a boolean parameter to determine behavior?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/147977/is-it-wrong-to-use-a-boolean-parameter-to-determine-behavior). TL;DR quote from the top answer in the link:

> Yes, this is likely a code smell, which would lead to unmaintainable code that is difficult to understand and that has a lower chance of being easily re-used.

The solution is to break positive and negative into two separate functions, then call a third function for the shared math logic to keep that DRY.

Your use of `oninput` and `onreset` has a thread on Stack Overflow as well: [addEventListener vs onclick](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6348494/addeventlistener-vs-onclick/35093997#35093997). I'd prefer `addEventListener`, but `oninput` seems acceptable here. I also prefer not to use `this` to refer to a form.

---

#### Possible rewrite

```js
const calculatePosterior = (prior, pTestGivenPos, pTestGivenNeg) =>
  prior === 0 || pTestGivenPos === 0 ? 0
    : 1 / (1 + pTestGivenNeg * (1 - prior) / (pTestGivenPos * prior))
;
const calculatePositivePosterior = (prior, sensitivity, specificity) =>
  calculatePosterior(prior, sensitivity, 1 - specificity)
;
const calculateNegativePosterior = (prior, sensitivity, specificity) =>
  calculatePosterior(prior, 1 - sensitivity, specificity)
;

const handlePosteriorRecalculation = ({target: {form}}) => {
  const posteriorFn = form["test-positive"].checked
    ? calculatePositivePosterior
    : calculateNegativePosterior
  ;
  form.posterior.value = posteriorFn(
    +form.incidence.value / 100000,
    +form.sensitivity.value / 100,
    +form.specificity.value / 100,
  ) * 100 + "%";
};
const bayesForm = document.getElementById("bayes-form");
bayesForm.addEventListener("input", handlePosteriorRecalculation);
bayesForm.addEventListener("reset", handlePosteriorRecalculation);

for (const input of document.getElementsByTagName("input")) {
  input.addEventListener("input", () => input.classList.add("modified"));
}
```

```html
<form id="bayes-form">
  <div>
    <label for="incidence">Incidence Rate</label>
    <input
      type="number"
      name="incidence"
      id="incidence"
      min="0"
      max="100000"
      step="1"
      placeholder="per 100 000"
      required
    >
  </div>
  <div>
    <label>Sensitivity
    <input
      type="number"
      id="sensitivity"
      name="sensitivity"
      min="0"
      max="100"
      step=".01"
      placeholder="in percent"
      required
    >
    </label>
  </div>
  <div>
    <label for="specificity">Specificity</label>
    <input
      type="number"
      name="specificity"
      id="specificity"
      min="0"
      max="100"
      step=".01"
      placeholder="in percent"
      required
    >
  </div>
  <div>
    <label for="test-positive">Test positive?</label>
    <input
      type="checkbox"
      name="test-positive"
      id="test-positive"
    >
  </div>
  <div>
    <label for="posterior">Likelihood to be infected:</label>
    <output name="posterior" id="posterior">
      Input not Valid
    </output>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: I do not quite understand the `this.posterior.value` comment, as far as I understood https://www.quirksmode.org/js/this.html `this` refers to its owner (in this case the form and not the entire window). I thought that this was a better idea because it uses in some sense local variables of the form instead of doing a global lookup with getElementById which seems like a weird practice coming from other programming languages.

Comment: thank you for the link to the `addEventListener vs onclick` comparison, I did not think about the fact that onclick does not allow multiple listeners and is therefore not a good idea

Comment: Yep, you're right! My mistake. Removed.

Comment: I am not sure if I would call the `test_positive` variable behaviour determining variable. In both cases I am calculating the posterior probability of being infected. So I am not changing the semantic control flow. Sure I need to handle those cases differently, but that is due to a mathematical technicality which I wanted to abstract away with `_calculatePosterior`. The fact that I only need to swap out `1-specificity` for `specificity` is an extremely technical detail which should not concern people using this function.

Comment: do you think that a CSS grid would be appropriate instead of the `<br>`? That would also align the input fields while allowing their labels to move above them when the screen becomes to slim I guess. Or is CSS grid overkill? Are there better methods?

Comment: good points about the code style otherwise - thanks :)

Comment: Regarding `1 - specificity`, I still feel my remark applies. I gathered that it's a technical detail the caller shouldn't control with any greater granularity than a boolean, but that's where the additional function layer might make sense: there's one function that does the formula and two wrapper functions that prepare the correct `specificity` and `sensitivity` values, eliminating booleans and conditions except at the original caller. In such a small codebase, it barely matters, but it's something to think about.

Comment: BTW, it's best to use LaTeX for formulas and type out the text rather than an image sceenshot, which is inaccessible to people with visual impairments and uses more bandwidth

Comment: but then you have a function which is only ever called by `_calculatePosterior` and never by any other function. This requires jumping around in the code adding complexity. There is also no way to name these functions in any way which would make `_calculatePosterior` easier to understand. At best the name is the same as I named the variables, but that information is already available to the reader.

Comment: I did use LaTeX (this is a picture of the preview of stackexchange), `codereview.stackexchange` detects latex as code and complains that I do not use code fences and did not allow me to post this even though it rendered it perfectly fine in the preview

Comment: OK, I added code so maybe my proposal will appear more concrete. You don't have to agree with it, and the app is too small for it to matter, but it seems like a pretty classic case of [the Software Engineering SE situation](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/147977/is-it-wrong-to-use-a-boolean-parameter-to-determine-behavior) to me. Not sure what happened with the LaTeX, but looks like you fixed it. Thanks for taking the time to do that, and great question overall!

Comment: I personally am strongly against your rewrite, as it reads a lot worse than the original JavaScript. Personal issues aside, you said to use spaces around the operators, but your rewrite has a few lines where the `+` operator doesn't have space after. Also, the semi-colons at the top are useless, as they are on an empty line, terminating no statements at all. They should be moved to the end of the line above. Additionally, you said to format the number to a more easily readable result, but you don't show any examples. on how to do it (like using the `toFixed()` method or `Intl.NumberFormat()`).

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel I appreciate the feedback! My style is more "modern" ES6 than OP's, which doesn't appeal to everyone immediately. The semicolons terminate the function statements. It'd be weird for me to recommend semicolons after every statement, then not use them. You can move them up a line if you want. The `+` is for type conversion, so it's a unary operator--the spacing only applies to binary ops. Regarding number conversion, I didn't want to change the functionality for my rewrite, so it's left as a suggestion, and there are plenty of resources on how to do that, if desired.

Comment: @ggorlen I actually didn't notice the commas at the end of those lines (the ones with the `+`). However, for this example, I wouldn't use `+` to convert to number. Invalid inputs, like `"cookies"`, will be parsed into `NaN` and all calculations will result into `NaN`s (showing `NaN%` in the output). Using `parseInt(<value>, 10)` will always convert to `0` instead. This may be a more desirable outcome. Also, regarding the semi-colons, I've tested and they are indeed terminating an empty line, not the arrow function. That one is terminated by the newline. If you write `alert(1)` before the [...]

Comment: @ggorlen [...] semi-colon, you will see that it is executed. If it was terminating the function statement, it would have to throw some kind of error (syntax error, for example), which doesn't happen at all. And regarding the last point, you did leave it as a single line suggestion, which I don't think that was expanded enough, in my opinion. A simple reference to the functions would be more than enough, without adding them to the code (in case the desired result is to have all decimal places being displayed).

Comment: Sure, maybe automatic semicolon insertion adds a second semicolon on the line above, but I'm going to add it regardless so I can delimit the function visually, and because I can't go wrong if I add it. OP didn't use validation, so again, I'm not extending their functionality. The input boxes are restricted to numbers, so `"cookies"` isn't a possible input. The `+` is just to make it visually explicit that this string is being coerced to a number, so it's a small improvement to communicate intent and improve readability ("hey, this input value is being treated as a number"), not a big deal.